# How to make a matrix from two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
import numpy as np

MC=np.array([1, 2, 3])
oo=np.array([4,5,6])

for i in range(0, len(MC)): 
    for j in range(0, len(oo)):
        H[i,j]=(MC[i],oo[j])   

print(oo)    
print(H)
```

I want an output matrix like this and I get an error (list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple):

H=[[(1,4),(1,5),(1,6)],[(2,4),(2,5),(2,6)],[(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)]]

Comment: Assuming the desired result should be a `numpy` 2D array `np.dstack(np.meshgrid(MC, oo)).swapaxes(0,1)`.

Comment: The error is not reproducible with the provided code.

Comment: Thanks for the code provided. This is exactly the error that I get.

Comment: Please read [mre]. The provided code raises *NameError: name 'H' is not defined*.

Comment: OK thanks! I was referring to the error that I get in my compiler.

Comment: What is `H`? From the error message I suspect it is a list.  If so, reread basic python about lists and their indexing.

Answer (score 3):

"I get an error" is quite unspecific. So you should provide more details. But I assume that you get a `NameError` since `H` is not defined anywhere before using it. But looking at you implementation I can't see how you would get the desired result anyway. If you generally don't know the length of the given arrays in advance you could try

```
H = []
for i in range(0, len(MC)):
    H.append([])
     for j in range(0, len(oo)):
         H[-1].append((MC[i], oo[j]))
```

That should give you the desired output. Or in my opinion even better, particulary in terms of readability:

```
H = []
for mc_el in MC:
    H.append([])
     for oo_el in oo:
         H[-1].append((mc_el, oo_el))
```

Or (inspired by nikoros' answer):

```
H = [[(MC_el, oo_el) for oo_el in oo] for MC_el in MC]
```

Comment: Thank you Bernie and nikoros , I added the error :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually iterating the arrays, you can combine `groupby` and `product` from `itertools`, you can create the required list of list of tuples in List-Comprehension

```py
>>> from itertools import groupby, product
>>> [list(product([k], oo)) for k,v in groupby(MC)]

[[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6)], [(2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6)], [(3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]]
```